# setting api key to restassured tests

Tags: rest-assured

I am trying to pass api key in restassured. From postman, i got the repsonse data using 'X-Api-Key' with value. But with rest assured, i am seeing null pointer exception

```
Response res = given()      
        .header("key","55af7bc105c9c2ee98e2abb32979fee")
        .when()
    .get ("https://mbaseurl/api/v1/search-listings/").then().
 //   contentType(ContentType.JSON).  // check that the content type return from the API is JSON
    extract().response();
```

I tried passing key value with .header("X-Api-Key", "value") but was not successful

Comment: Where are you seeing a null pointer?

Comment: I was seeing it when printing out the response. Thanks, the issue is resolved now.

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String, String> pMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        pMap.put("apiKey","yourAPIKEY");
        pMap.put("format","json");
        pMap.put("show","storeId,`storeType`,name,city,region");
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.